# Iterate through a string (STL)

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I want to iterate through a sting, from the first element to the last element but when I execute the following code:

```
for (string::iterator i =beads.begin(); i != beads.end(); i++);
```

I couldn't get to the last element. So I have changed it to :

```
for (string::iterator i =beads.begin(); i <= beads.end(); i++);
```

compiler reported errors, saying that it is not incrementable because `beads.end()+1` does not exist.

May I know if there is any elegant way to solve this so that I can get to the last element?

**Correction:**

Sorry, in actual fact, I was performing decremental operation.

I changed it to incremental operation just to make it easier for everyone to see. I forgot that the beads.end() is a past-the-end iterator.

I was actually using `for (string::iterator i =pos; i >= beads.begin(); i--);`. Because beads.begin() is not a before-the-start operator, so I can't use `for (string::iterator i =pos; i != beads.begin(); i--);`, otherwise I will never get to the first element.

However, compiler reported errors as `beads.begin()-1` does not exist.

May I know how to solve the problem if I am performing decremental iteration?

Comment: The first one is correct (but the semicolon at the end is questionable). What do you mean you couldn't get the last element?

Comment: The first one should work. Please show more code

Comment: @0x499602D2 When i = beads.end(), the code under the for loop won't be executed.

Comment: Post an MCVE or it didn't happen.

Comment: @lxjhk `beads.end()` is the past-the-end iterator. It's a sentinel value that represents the end of the range. When `i == beads.end()` it should've gone through the entire range, so that code is correct. Give us an MCVE.

Comment: @0x499602D2 sorry, in actual fact, I was performing decremental operation. `for (string::iterator i =pos; i >= beads.begin(); i--)`  I changed it to  incremental operation just to make it easier for everyone to see. I forgot that the beads.end() is a past-the-end iterator.

Comment: @lxjhk Can you post a minimal program that represents the problem? Also, consider using reverse iterators (`rbegin()` and `rend()`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Thanks for your reply. rend()/rbegin() can't really apply in my case as the `pos` is actually of type `string::iterator` not `string::reverse_iterator`. I really appreciate your help and your suggestions.

Comment: @lxjhk If you're walking backwards then don't use `iterator`, use `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: @lxjhk: If you have a `string::iterator`, you can turn it into a `std::reverse_iterator<string::iterator>`.

Comment: @MooingDuck Or `std::string::reverse_iterator` (which seems clearer to me, although they both define the same type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT: Thanks James Kanze for suggesting using the existing reverse iterators]**

Since it turns out that `std::string` already does supply reverse iterators via [`rbegin()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rbegin/) and [`rend()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rend/) methods, by far the simplest way is to use them -- *provided that you don't need to access the string starting at position `i` in the usual "forward" direction in the loop body*:

```
for (string::reverse_iterator i = beads.rend(); i != beads.rend(); ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Failing that, you can use

```
for (string::iterator ii = beads.end(); ii != beads.begin(); --ii) {
    string::iterator i = ii - 1;
    // Use i, NOT ii from now on
}
```

Yes, it's ugly.  But the only real alternatives that avoid having to duplicate the loop body are introducing a special `finalIter` flag variable (just as messy), or changing to a `while` loop:

```
{
    string::iterator i = beads.end();
    while (i != beads.begin()) {
        --i;
        ...
    }
}
```

The extra braces are to keep the scope of `i` localised; you might not need them.  **[EDIT #2: As noticed by James Kanze, since we need to handle the empty-string case, we can use a `while` instead of an `if` plus a `do ... while`.]**

Comment: Another method is to use indexes instead of iterators.  The string can be treated as an array of characters.

Comment: I have adopted your first suggestion. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Two questions: first, what's wrong with just using `std::string::reverse_iterator` and `std::strring::rbegin` and `std::string::rend`?.  You don't need to create your own.  And second: why use `if` and then `do ... while`, rather than just using a simple `while`?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Whoops, I didn't realise `std::string` had `rbegin()` and `rend()`!  I'll fix that.  Re: just using a `while`: How would you allow the loop body to execute when `i == beads.begin()`?

Comment: @j_random_hacker You wouldn't.  If you're using the half open interval that dominates C and C++, you wouldn't; if you want to, you'd increment the iterator (after verifying that it isn't `end`) before hand,  You're additional `if` doesn't change anything in this regard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I'm confused -- your first comment about the `while` was still in the context of using forward iterators, right?  So why does your second comment talk about incrementing, and about checking for `end()`?  We should be decrementing and checking for `begin()`, surely.

Comment: @j_random_hacker My comment on using `while` instead of `if` and then `do ... while` concerns your second example.  Where the condition in the `if` and the condition in the `do ... while` are identical.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably still to use a reverse iterator:

```
for ( auto i = std::string::reverse_iterator( pos ); i != beads.rend(); ++ i ) {
    //  ...
}
```

This assumes that you don't want to iterate over `pos`; it you
do, you must ensure that it is not `beads.end()`, and then
initialize `i` with `std::string::reverse_iterator( pos + 1 )`.